# Password toggle view button not working on other tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I have been following the w3schools tutorial for tabs, and then used another tutorial for a password toggle button. It works perfectly on the inital tab (login tab), but on the remaining tabs the password toggle button stops working. I have no idea why it ceases to work. I am using this for the ui of a python application. At this stage I am simply trying to design the ui. Please keep in mind I am still quite new to html/css/java so you may find a lot of newbie errors. Any help is greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--- IMPORT STYLESHEET --->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<!--- START --->

<body>
<div class="window">

    <!--- TAB MENU BAR --->
    <div>
        <div class="tabmenu">
            <button class="tablinkers" onclick="openPage(event, 'Login')" id="defaultOpen">Login</button>
            <button class="tablinkers" onclick="openPage(event, 'Register')">Register</button>
            <button class="tablinkers" onclick="openPage(event, 'Renew')">Renew</button>
            <button class="tablinkers" onclick="openPage(event, 'Help')">Help</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--- LOGIN --->
    <div id="Login" class="tabpane">
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="typetext" name="usernameLogin" placeholder="Username"><br>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="password" name="passwordLogin" placeholder="Password">
                <i class="material-icons visibility">visibility_off</i>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="buttoncss" name="buttonRegister">
        </form>
    </div>

    <!--- REGISTER --->
    <div id="Register" class="tabpane">
        <form>
            <input type="email" class="typetext" name="emailRegister" placeholder="Email"><br>
            <input type="text" class="typetext" name="usernameRegister" placeholder="Username"><br>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
                <i class="material-icons visibility">visibility_off</i>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="typetext" name="licensekeyRegister" placeholder="License Key"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="buttonRegister">
        </form>
    </div>

    <!--- RENEW --->
    <div id="Renew" class="tabpane">
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="typetext" name="usernameRenew" placeholder="Username"><br>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="password" name="passwordLogin" placeholder="Password">
                <i class="material-icons visibility">visibility_off</i>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="typetext" name="licensekeyRenew" placeholder="License Key"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="buttonRegister">
        </form>
    </div>

    <!--- HELP --->
    <div id="Help" class="tabpane">
        help
    </div>

</div>
<!--- IMPORT JAVA --->
<script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

/* START CSS FOR TABS */

/* Define window size. Change before release. */
.window {
    border: 1px solid black
}

/* Container holding tab buttons */
.tabmenu {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    float: left;
}

/* The tab buttons */
.tabmenu button {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 80px;
    border: 0px; /* Button border. */
}

.tabmenu button:hover {
    background-color: #7289da;
}

.tabmenu button:active {
    background-color: firebrick;
}

.tabmenu button:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.tabpane {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

/* START CSS FOR LINE EDIT, PASSWORD, PWD TOGGLE, BUTTON */

/* Line Edit Class (type="text") */
.typetext {
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

/* Password Class (type="password") */
.input-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
.input-container input {
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
i {
    position: absolute;
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: default;
    margin-left: 180px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// START JAVA FOR TABS
function openPage(evt, pageName) {
    //Declare variables
    var i, tabpane, tablinkers;

    // Get all elements with class="tabpane" and hide them
    tabpane = document.getElementsByClassName("tabpane");
    for (i = 0; i < tabpane.length; i++) {
        tabpane[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinkers" and remove the class active
    tablinkers = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinkers")
    for (i = 0; i < tablinkers.length; i++) {
        tablinkers[i].className = tablinkers[i].className.replace(" active", "")
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";


}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();


// START JAVA FOR PWD TOGGLE
const visibilityToggle = document.querySelector('.visibility');

const input = document.querySelector('.input-container input');

var password = true;

visibilityToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (password) {
        input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        visibilityToggle.innerHTML = 'visibility';
    } else {
        input.setAttribute('type', 'password');
        visibilityToggle.innerHTML = 'visibility_off';
    }
    password = !password;

});
```

Comment: @Spectric I have barely used java before. I honestly dont know what the difference is?

Comment: [JavaScript Is Not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/) :)

Comment: Javascript is run in a browser. Java is compiled. Javascript is limited to web-development while Java expands to web applications, back end development and so forth.

Comment: @Spectric Ahh I see. Thank you! Do you have any idea as to why I am having the current issue?

Comment: @Michael.C Hmmm... I'll take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addEventListener` only applies the event listener to the first element, since `querySelector` only returns the first element in hierarchical order, rather than `querySelectorAll`, which returns an array.

The following code below uses jQuery, because it is the most efficient. If you would like, I can convert it to plain JS.

```js
// START JAVA FOR TABS
function openPage(evt, pageName) {
    //Declare variables
    var i, tabpane, tablinkers;

    // Get all elements with class="tabpane" and hide them
    tabpane = document.getElementsByClassName("tabpane");
    for (i = 0; i < tabpane.length; i++) {
        tabpane[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinkers" and remove the class active
    tablinkers = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinkers")
    for (i = 0; i < tablinkers.length; i++) {
        tablinkers[i].className = tablinkers[i].className.replace(" active", "")
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();


// START JAVA FOR PWD TOGGLE
const visibilityToggle = document.querySelector('.visibility');

$('.visibility').on('click', function() {
    let elem = $('input', $(this).parent());
    let cur = elem.attr('type');
    if (cur == "password") {
        elem.attr('type', 'text');
    } else {
        elem.attr('type', 'password');
    }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

/* START CSS FOR TABS */


/* Define window size. Change before release. */

.window {
  border: 1px solid black
}


/* Container holding tab buttons */

.tabmenu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: left;
}


/* The tab buttons */

.tabmenu button {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 32px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 0px;
  /* Button border. */
}

.tabmenu button:hover {
  background-color: #7289da;
}

.tabmenu button:active {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

.tabmenu button:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.tabpane {
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* START CSS FOR LINE EDIT, PASSWORD, PWD TOGGLE, BUTTON */


/* Line Edit Class (type="text") */

.typetext {
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}


/* Password Class (type="password") */

.input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.input-container input {
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

i {
  position: absolute;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: default;
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--- IMPORT STYLESHEET --->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!--- START --->

<body>
  <div class="window">

    <!--- TAB MENU BAR --->
    <div>
      <div class="tabmenu">
        <button class="tablinkers" onclick="openPage(event, 'Login')" id="defaultOpen">Login</button>
        <button class="tablinkers" onclick="openPage(event, 'Register')">Register</button>
        <button class="tablinkers" onclick="openPage(event, 'Renew')">Renew</button>
        <button class="tablinkers" onclick="openPage(event, 'Help')">Help</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--- LOGIN --->
    <div id="Login" class="tabpane">
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="typetext" name="usernameLogin" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <div class="input-container">
          <input type="password" name="passwordLogin" placeholder="Password">
          <i class="material-icons visibility">visibility_off</i>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="buttoncss" name="buttonRegister">
      </form>
    </div>

    <!--- REGISTER --->
    <div id="Register" class="tabpane">
      <form>
        <input type="email" class="typetext" name="emailRegister" placeholder="Email"><br>
        <input type="text" class="typetext" name="usernameRegister" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <div class="input-container">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
          <i class="material-icons visibility">visibility_off</i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="typetext" name="licensekeyRegister" placeholder="License Key"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="buttonRegister">
      </form>
    </div>

    <!--- RENEW --->
    <div id="Renew" class="tabpane">
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="typetext" name="usernameRenew" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <div class="input-container">
          <input type="password" name="passwordLogin" placeholder="Password">
          <i class="material-icons visibility">visibility_off</i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="typetext" name="licensekeyRenew" placeholder="License Key"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="buttonRegister">
      </form>
    </div>

    <!--- HELP --->
    <div id="Help" class="tabpane">
      help
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--- IMPORT JAVA --->
  <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

In Plain JS:

```js
// START JAVA FOR TABS
function openPage(evt, pageName) {
    //Declare variables
    var i, tabpane, tablinkers;

    // Get all elements with class="tabpane" and hide them
    tabpane = document.getElementsByClassName("tabpane");
    for (i = 0; i < tabpane.length; i++) {
        tabpane[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinkers" and remove the class active
    tablinkers = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinkers")
    for (i = 0; i < tablinkers.length; i++) {
        tablinkers[i].className = tablinkers[i].className.replace(" active", "")
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();


// START JAVA FOR PWD TOGGLE
const visibilityToggles = document.querySelectorAll('.visibility');

for(var i = 0; i < visibilityToggles.length; i++){
  visibilityToggles[i].addEventListener("click", togglePasswordVisible);
}

function togglePasswordVisible(e){
  var input = (e.target).parentElement.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  if(input.type == "password"){
    input.type="text";
    e.target.innerHTML = "visibility";
  }else{
    input.type="password";
    e.target.innerHTML = "visibility_off";
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

/* START CSS FOR TABS */


/* Define window size. Change before release. */

.window {
  border: 1px solid black
}


/* Container holding tab buttons */

.tabmenu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: left;
}


/* The tab buttons */

.tabmenu button {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 32px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 0px;
  /* Button border. */
}

.tabmenu button:hover {
  background-color: #7289da;
}

.tabmenu button:active {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

.tabmenu button:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.tabpane {
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* START CSS FOR LINE EDIT, PASSWORD, PWD TOGGLE, BUTTON */


/* Line Edit Class (type="text") */

.typetext {
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}


/* Password Class (type="password") */

.input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.input-container input {
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

i {
  position: absolute;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: default;
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--- IMPORT STYLESHEET --->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!--- START --->

<body>
  <div class="window">

    <!--- TAB MENU BAR --->
    <div>
      <div class="tabmenu">
        <button class="tablinkers" onclick="openPage(event, 'Login')" id="defaultOpen">Login</button>
        <button class="tablinkers" onclick="openPage(event, 'Register')">Register</button>
        <button class="tablinkers" onclick="openPage(event, 'Renew')">Renew</button>
        <button class="tablinkers" onclick="openPage(event, 'Help')">Help</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--- LOGIN --->
    <div id="Login" class="tabpane">
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="typetext" name="usernameLogin" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <div class="input-container">
          <input type="password" name="passwordLogin" placeholder="Password">
          <i class="material-icons visibility">visibility_off</i>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="buttoncss" name="buttonRegister">
      </form>
    </div>

    <!--- REGISTER --->
    <div id="Register" class="tabpane">
      <form>
        <input type="email" class="typetext" name="emailRegister" placeholder="Email"><br>
        <input type="text" class="typetext" name="usernameRegister" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <div class="input-container">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
          <i class="material-icons visibility">visibility_off</i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="typetext" name="licensekeyRegister" placeholder="License Key"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="buttonRegister">
      </form>
    </div>

    <!--- RENEW --->
    <div id="Renew" class="tabpane">
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="typetext" name="usernameRenew" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <div class="input-container">
          <input type="password" name="passwordLogin" placeholder="Password">
          <i class="material-icons visibility">visibility_off</i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="typetext" name="licensekeyRenew" placeholder="License Key"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="buttonRegister">
      </form>
    </div>

    <!--- HELP --->
    <div id="Help" class="tabpane">
      help
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--- IMPORT JAVA --->
  <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you so much! It would be great to have it in plain java script.

Comment: Thank you! There is one new issue, the icon isn't changing when clicked now?

Comment: @Michael.C All the best ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as others said, is that you define visibilityToggle just once, when the page loads, so just the first icon get attached an Event Listener.

You have to attach the Event Listener to all of them, like so:

```js
// START JAVA FOR PWD TOGGLE
let visibilityToggles = document.querySelectorAll('.visibility');
    
for (const toggle of visibilityToggles) {
        
    const input = toggle.previousElementSibling;
    var password = true;
    
    toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (password) {
            input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            toggle.innerHTML = 'visibility';
        } else {
            input.setAttribute('type', 'password');
            toggle.innerHTML = 'visibility_off';
        }
        password = !password;
    });
}
```